# Looking for pirushim on Rabeinu Bachye al Hatorah

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, pentateuch-chumash, rishonim

Looking for pirushim on Rabeinu Bachye al Hatorah. Books similar to Ha'ezrach Beyisrael. Specifically on the more cryptic passages.

Comment: Welcome, Eliezer. Does the Mosad HaRav Kook edition have any explanatory notes? Some of their other works do. Not extensive artscroll-level notes, but they do sometimes explain the tricky passages, for example Rabbi Shavell's edition of Kitvei Ramban has some good notes.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of any traditional commentaries, but [Oz Vehadar has put out a full explanation of Rabbeinu Bahya](https://ozvehadar.us/rabbeinu-bechaye-hamevuar/). Notes and explanations, nikkud and also a full set of sources. The Mossad Harav Kook version has some smaller notes. If you're struggling with Rabbeinu Bahya, maybe try looking back at explanations on the Ramban who he based much of his commentary on.

Comment: Wow 10 volumes. Seems like a lot of commentary. Just curious, have you use the Oz v'Hadar and if so what do you see as the pros and cons of the commentary.

Comment: Haven't seen this set myself. From my experience, Oz Vehadar "hamevuar" notes can sometimes be a little unnecessary or not answer harder questions, but they're a go-to if you're struggling. The only problem is the price!

Comment: does it explain the secretive stuff?